# Does static methods create objects when class is loaded

Tags: java, static-methods

```
public class FactoryProducer {

    public static AbstractFactory getFactory(String choice){

        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("ENTITIES")){
            System.out.println("entities factory created with out calling");
             return new LoadEntityFactory();
          } 
          elseif(choice.equals.IgnoreCase("UNITS"))
              return new UnitFactory();


       }


    }
```

LoadEntity Class

```
public class LoadEntityFactory extends AbstractFactory {

    @Override
    public loadEntities getLoadEntity(String entity) {
        if(entity==null){
            return null;
        }else if (entity.equalsIgnoreCase("categories")) {

            return new LoadCategoryEntity();
        }
        else if (entity.equalsIgnoreCase("books")) {
            return new LoadBookEntity();
        }
        else if (entity.equalsIgnoreCase("author")) {
            return new LoadAuthorEntity();
        }
        else if (entity.equalsIgnoreCase("publisher")) {
            return new LoadPublisherEntity();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Now my Question When I call FactoryProducer.getFactory("entities").Will it create three objects, two objects(entity and unit) will be created when class is loaded into JVM and one when I call the static method?

Comment: which three object created when FactoryProducer.getFactory("entities") method call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All methods are executed only when they are called. Not on class loading. If you want to do something when a class is loaded, then use static initializer block.

> When I call FactoryProducer.getFactory("entities").Will it create three objects, two objects(entity and unit) will be created when class is loaded into JVM and one when I call the static method?

- The method `getFactory` will execute only when it is called. Not when class is loaded.
- as you pass `"entities"`, first `if` condition will be true and `LoadEntityFactory` will be instantiated when it is invoked using `new LoadEntityFactory`
- The `else` condition will not be true and hence `new UnitFactory` will not be called and `UnitFactory` object is not created.

Comment: You mean static methods does not initialize anything in it when a class is loaded?

Comment: @Niks No static methods are not called when class is loaded.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar. You're somehow interpreting the question in reverse.